# Flatten Array from 2d to 1D with same length

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, vectorization, gensim

I need to flat (2,300) array to (,300) array. Maybe flat is not right term but, I want to add each element in order then get mean of these 2 element and create (,300).I think manually change could be work , but since its loop i couldnt find solution yet.

Tried to read documentation but couldnt find it so far and search for numpy options but couldnt find solution yet.

```
[[ 1.56250000e-01 -2.18750000e-01 -2.81250000e-01 -2.26562500e-01
  -8.78906250e-02  4.08203125e-01  1.66992188e-01  1.68457031e-02
   3.20312500e-01 -5.22460938e-02 -3.19824219e-02  5.90820312e-02
   1.32812500e-01 -1.55273438e-01  2.87109375e-01  1.30859375e-01
   8.88671875e-02  4.56542969e-02 -4.37011719e-02 -4.96093750e-01
   5.85937500e-02  1.35742188e-01 -1.81884766e-02  7.32421875e-02
  -2.16796875e-01  5.66406250e-02 -1.66015625e-01  4.66308594e-02
  -1.04492188e-01  1.65039062e-01 -2.61718750e-01  3.27148438e-02
  -2.12890625e-01  3.63281250e-01 -2.80761719e-02 -2.40234375e-01
   1.21093750e-01  2.75390625e-01 -4.49218750e-02 -1.44531250e-01
  -1.61132812e-01  1.75781250e-01  1.69921875e-01  2.94921875e-01
   3.41796875e-01  3.02124023e-03 -4.90722656e-02  9.88769531e-03
   2.21679688e-01 -3.53515625e-01 -2.83203125e-01 -1.35742188e-01
  -2.53906250e-02 -2.14843750e-01  1.51367188e-01  3.73046875e-01
   4.68750000e-02  2.40478516e-02 -1.77734375e-01  2.49023438e-01
  -5.85937500e-02  9.94873047e-03 -1.93359375e-01  1.38671875e-01
  -1.30859375e-01 -4.34570312e-02 -5.54199219e-02  2.50000000e-01
  -2.36328125e-01  3.12500000e-01  4.66796875e-01 -6.05468750e-02
   2.25585938e-01 -2.26562500e-01 -4.21875000e-01 -2.11914062e-01
  -1.37695312e-01 -1.56250000e-01  2.39257812e-02 -3.55468750e-01
  -2.28515625e-01  3.82812500e-01  8.49609375e-02  4.00390625e-01
  -4.19921875e-02  9.91210938e-02  6.74438477e-03  3.59375000e-01
   9.42382812e-02  6.93359375e-02 -2.16796875e-01 -2.34375000e-01
  -2.02148438e-01  9.94873047e-03  1.38671875e-01  1.24511719e-01
   2.89062500e-01  1.10839844e-01 -6.49414062e-02 -4.08203125e-01
  -4.37500000e-01  2.33154297e-02  1.02539062e-01  2.19726562e-01
  -2.10937500e-01  9.47265625e-02  2.94921875e-01  3.14941406e-02
   2.92968750e-01 -1.28906250e-01 -1.65039062e-01 -1.66992188e-01
   1.49414062e-01 -1.44531250e-01 -1.22558594e-01  6.39648438e-02
  -2.48046875e-01 -3.30078125e-01  3.93066406e-02 -1.69921875e-01
   4.80957031e-02 -2.01171875e-01 -4.10156250e-01  1.65039062e-01
   2.29492188e-01 -1.45507812e-01 -2.53906250e-01 -2.27539062e-01
   1.33789062e-01  6.83593750e-02 -8.69140625e-02  4.15039062e-02
  -1.96289062e-01  1.69921875e-01  6.54296875e-02  6.34765625e-02
   1.22070312e-01  1.28906250e-01 -4.29687500e-02 -1.12792969e-01
   1.22070312e-01 -1.85546875e-01 -2.89062500e-01 -2.91015625e-01
  -1.98242188e-01  2.50000000e-01  2.46093750e-01  2.14843750e-01
  -1.81640625e-01  6.98852539e-03  3.35937500e-01 -1.90429688e-01
  -1.95312500e-02  4.23828125e-01 -1.04980469e-01 -7.81250000e-02
  -1.31835938e-01 -1.21582031e-01 -1.50756836e-02  1.92382812e-01
   9.03320312e-03  1.70898438e-01  2.83203125e-01 -1.08398438e-01
  -5.07812500e-02 -4.58984375e-02 -1.44531250e-01 -1.38671875e-01
  -3.55468750e-01 -6.44531250e-02 -1.21582031e-01  2.12402344e-02
  -4.68750000e-01  2.34375000e-02 -1.48437500e-01 -1.45507812e-01
   6.98242188e-02 -4.23828125e-01 -3.73535156e-02  1.45507812e-01
  -3.10546875e-01  1.82617188e-01  1.31835938e-01  6.49414062e-02
   3.04687500e-01  2.11914062e-01 -1.84570312e-01 -7.22656250e-02
   1.39648438e-01  5.22460938e-02 -1.01562500e-01 -2.07031250e-01
  -3.98437500e-01 -2.91015625e-01 -1.37695312e-01  3.76953125e-01
  -1.37695312e-01 -1.91406250e-01 -4.05273438e-02 -5.61523438e-02
   2.20947266e-02  3.93066406e-02 -3.39843750e-01  9.32617188e-02
   3.75000000e-01  3.66210938e-02 -2.14843750e-02 -1.67968750e-01
  -3.12500000e-01  1.81884766e-02  1.75781250e-01 -2.79541016e-02
  -4.02343750e-01 -5.20019531e-02  8.88671875e-02 -5.00000000e-01
  -1.25976562e-01 -9.37500000e-02 -2.85156250e-01 -1.66015625e-01
  -1.92382812e-01  2.38281250e-01 -7.78198242e-03  2.00195312e-01
  -1.07421875e-01  2.71484375e-01 -1.25000000e-01 -1.30462646e-03
  -3.88183594e-02 -2.34375000e-01 -1.07910156e-01  4.68750000e-02
   8.78906250e-03 -2.53906250e-01  6.78710938e-02 -6.15234375e-02
  -5.20019531e-02 -9.96093750e-02  2.59765625e-01 -4.07714844e-02
   1.03515625e-01  1.22680664e-02 -1.94335938e-01 -3.65234375e-01
   2.57812500e-01 -4.19921875e-02  6.73828125e-02  1.73828125e-01
   3.29589844e-02 -2.13867188e-01  4.83989716e-05  7.86132812e-02
   7.86132812e-02  1.38671875e-01  1.07910156e-01 -4.10156250e-01
   1.72851562e-01 -1.78710938e-01  6.56127930e-03  1.19628906e-01
   2.55859375e-01 -4.76074219e-02  5.32226562e-02 -3.20312500e-01
  -2.57812500e-01  1.11816406e-01 -1.67968750e-01 -2.73437500e-01
  -4.19921875e-01  2.07031250e-01  8.10546875e-02 -1.47460938e-01
   6.28662109e-03 -5.61523438e-02 -6.25610352e-03  1.25000000e-01
   3.10058594e-02  2.83203125e-02 -3.90625000e-01 -1.04003906e-01
   1.82617188e-01  4.61425781e-02 -1.11389160e-03  2.50000000e-01
   1.77734375e-01 -1.07910156e-01 -3.97949219e-02 -1.62109375e-01
   1.44653320e-02  4.49218750e-01 -1.12792969e-01  1.76757812e-01
  -1.74804688e-01 -3.04687500e-01  3.94531250e-01 -5.93261719e-02
   1.15234375e-01  4.05883789e-03 -2.12890625e-01  2.98828125e-01]
 [ 2.01171875e-01 -2.75878906e-02 -1.13281250e-01  1.90429688e-01
  -2.98828125e-01 -1.91406250e-01  1.83593750e-01 -2.43164062e-01
   3.61328125e-02 -9.32617188e-02 -1.60156250e-01  2.42919922e-02
   4.71191406e-02 -1.25976562e-01 -2.24609375e-02  1.20117188e-01
  -3.57055664e-03 -8.44726562e-02  1.56250000e-01 -4.39453125e-01
   3.53515625e-01  2.23632812e-01 -3.44238281e-02  1.06445312e-01
  -3.82812500e-01  3.02734375e-01 -1.39648438e-01  3.98437500e-01
   1.69921875e-01  2.72216797e-02 -1.04492188e-01  1.77734375e-01
  -1.93359375e-01 -1.87500000e-01 -6.05468750e-02 -2.29492188e-01
   3.61328125e-01  3.02734375e-01 -1.21093750e-01 -2.23632812e-01
   3.81469727e-05  8.88671875e-02  1.31835938e-01 -5.90820312e-02
   2.43164062e-01  3.00292969e-02  1.88476562e-01  2.36816406e-02
   2.20703125e-01 -2.96875000e-01 -3.63281250e-01 -1.71875000e-01
   1.56250000e-01 -3.45703125e-01 -3.02734375e-01  2.34375000e-01
  -1.01074219e-01 -1.25000000e-01 -6.34765625e-02  4.16015625e-01
  -3.02734375e-01 -3.84765625e-01 -1.16699219e-01  1.08886719e-01
   9.57031250e-02  1.26953125e-01 -6.00585938e-02 -2.59765625e-01
   2.61718750e-01  1.72851562e-01  1.63085938e-01  2.91015625e-01
  -5.85937500e-02 -3.30078125e-01 -2.15148926e-03 -5.46875000e-01
   3.08593750e-01  1.92382812e-01  1.02539062e-01  4.12597656e-02
   7.27539062e-02  2.37304688e-01  5.05371094e-02  4.15039062e-03
  -4.19921875e-02 -9.71679688e-02 -3.57055664e-03  7.03125000e-02
   2.96875000e-01 -1.36718750e-01 -2.68554688e-02  1.39648438e-01
  -2.27539062e-01 -1.55273438e-01 -2.66113281e-02  2.16796875e-01
   4.41406250e-01 -1.62109375e-01  5.51757812e-02  1.35498047e-02
  -8.49609375e-02 -1.75781250e-01 -4.39453125e-01  6.73828125e-02
  -2.31445312e-01  1.45507812e-01  3.61328125e-02  5.44433594e-02
   2.53906250e-01 -2.91015625e-01  6.25000000e-02 -3.20312500e-01
   1.57226562e-01 -6.10351562e-02  1.37695312e-01  2.35351562e-01
  -2.13623047e-02  1.37695312e-01 -7.14111328e-03 -2.36328125e-01
   9.88769531e-03 -1.04492188e-01 -2.43164062e-01  2.32421875e-01
   4.27246094e-02 -3.81469727e-04  7.86132812e-02  1.96289062e-01
   1.05957031e-01  7.32421875e-02  3.73535156e-02 -1.70898438e-01
  -1.80664062e-01  3.88183594e-02  2.43164062e-01 -7.32421875e-02
   1.74804688e-01 -1.21459961e-02  2.04101562e-01 -1.35742188e-01
   9.13085938e-02 -5.50781250e-01 -7.81250000e-02 -4.22363281e-02
   2.14843750e-01 -1.63085938e-01  1.20117188e-01 -5.95092773e-03
   3.34472656e-02 -2.53906250e-01  3.02734375e-01  5.93261719e-02
   2.18750000e-01 -5.00488281e-03  1.46484375e-01 -9.57031250e-02
  -1.68945312e-01  2.52685547e-02  9.09423828e-03  1.01562500e-01
   1.07910156e-01 -6.88476562e-02  2.91015625e-01  7.56835938e-03
  -1.95312500e-01 -3.00781250e-01 -1.73828125e-01  2.89062500e-01
  -1.13769531e-01 -1.27929688e-01 -2.59765625e-01  2.14843750e-01
   2.61230469e-02  4.56542969e-02 -1.78710938e-01 -2.39257812e-01
   2.19726562e-02 -2.26562500e-01 -3.35937500e-01 -6.15234375e-02
  -4.14062500e-01  1.22070312e-01 -1.56250000e-01  6.64062500e-02
   6.32812500e-01  9.42382812e-02 -2.77343750e-01  1.30859375e-01
  -7.76367188e-02  1.77734375e-01  4.24804688e-02 -1.41601562e-01
  -1.72851562e-01 -1.39648438e-01  1.77734375e-01  9.03320312e-02
  -4.72656250e-01 -7.17773438e-02 -1.12792969e-01  1.42578125e-01
   1.06445312e-01  1.31835938e-01 -2.32421875e-01 -3.78417969e-02
   4.37500000e-01 -1.16699219e-01 -4.73632812e-02  2.10937500e-01
   6.34765625e-02 -9.88769531e-03 -1.25976562e-01 -4.76074219e-03
  -1.14257812e-01  1.13281250e-01  4.17480469e-02 -3.57421875e-01
   2.27539062e-01  6.10351562e-02 -1.64062500e-01  4.46777344e-02
  -4.53125000e-01  2.92968750e-01 -1.26953125e-01  2.04101562e-01
  -3.41796875e-01  1.62109375e-01  1.68945312e-01 -1.95312500e-01
  -1.32812500e-01 -3.69140625e-01 -1.73828125e-01  2.22656250e-01
  -5.41992188e-02  9.03320312e-02 -8.00781250e-02 -9.27734375e-02
  -9.81445312e-02 -1.60156250e-01  5.23437500e-01  8.05664062e-02
   1.38671875e-01  1.97265625e-01 -4.04296875e-01 -4.04296875e-01
  -9.08203125e-02 -2.62451172e-02  5.10253906e-02  3.90625000e-01
   3.65234375e-01 -2.50000000e-01 -4.02343750e-01  5.20019531e-02
  -1.11694336e-02 -3.47656250e-01  2.08007812e-01 -2.55859375e-01
   4.90722656e-02 -2.65625000e-01 -1.24023438e-01 -3.26171875e-01
   1.44531250e-01 -1.88476562e-01 -8.05664062e-02 -2.85156250e-01
   1.33789062e-01  1.56250000e-01  3.27148438e-02 -2.81982422e-02
  -1.05468750e-01 -4.56542969e-02  2.21679688e-01  3.22265625e-01
  -2.06054688e-01 -1.20117188e-01 -9.37500000e-02  1.00585938e-01
   1.90429688e-01 -3.63281250e-01 -2.75390625e-01  1.87500000e-01
   1.63085938e-01 -7.51953125e-02  3.59375000e-01  1.75781250e-01
   1.45507812e-01  2.69531250e-01 -3.43750000e-01 -2.92968750e-01
   1.06445312e-01  3.29589844e-02  2.23632812e-01  2.59765625e-01
  -2.71484375e-01  2.84423828e-02  2.11914062e-01 -4.68750000e-01
   7.71484375e-02 -3.10546875e-01 -1.62109375e-01  4.17968750e-01]]
```

To change this

```
[ 1.56250000e-01 -2.18750000e-01 -2.81250000e-01 -2.26562500e-01
 -8.78906250e-02  4.08203125e-01  1.66992188e-01  1.68457031e-02
  3.20312500e-01 -5.22460938e-02 -3.19824219e-02  5.90820312e-02
  1.32812500e-01 -1.55273438e-01  2.87109375e-01  1.30859375e-01
  8.88671875e-02  4.56542969e-02 -4.37011719e-02 -4.96093750e-01
  5.85937500e-02  1.35742188e-01 -1.81884766e-02  7.32421875e-02
 -2.16796875e-01  5.66406250e-02 -1.66015625e-01  4.66308594e-02
 -1.04492188e-01  1.65039062e-01 -2.61718750e-01  3.27148438e-02
 -2.12890625e-01  3.63281250e-01 -2.80761719e-02 -2.40234375e-01
  1.21093750e-01  2.75390625e-01 -4.49218750e-02 -1.44531250e-01
 -1.61132812e-01  1.75781250e-01  1.69921875e-01  2.94921875e-01
  3.41796875e-01  3.02124023e-03 -4.90722656e-02  9.88769531e-03
  2.21679688e-01 -3.53515625e-01 -2.83203125e-01 -1.35742188e-01
 -2.53906250e-02 -2.14843750e-01  1.51367188e-01  3.73046875e-01
  4.68750000e-02  2.40478516e-02 -1.77734375e-01  2.49023438e-01
 -5.85937500e-02  9.94873047e-03 -1.93359375e-01  1.38671875e-01
 -1.30859375e-01 -4.34570312e-02 -5.54199219e-02  2.50000000e-01
 -2.36328125e-01  3.12500000e-01  4.66796875e-01 -6.05468750e-02
  2.25585938e-01 -2.26562500e-01 -4.21875000e-01 -2.11914062e-01
 -1.37695312e-01 -1.56250000e-01  2.39257812e-02 -3.55468750e-01
 -2.28515625e-01  3.82812500e-01  8.49609375e-02  4.00390625e-01
 -4.19921875e-02  9.91210938e-02  6.74438477e-03  3.59375000e-01
  9.42382812e-02  6.93359375e-02 -2.16796875e-01 -2.34375000e-01
 -2.02148438e-01  9.94873047e-03  1.38671875e-01  1.24511719e-01
  2.89062500e-01  1.10839844e-01 -6.49414062e-02 -4.08203125e-01
 -4.37500000e-01  2.33154297e-02  1.02539062e-01  2.19726562e-01
 -2.10937500e-01  9.47265625e-02  2.94921875e-01  3.14941406e-02
  2.92968750e-01 -1.28906250e-01 -1.65039062e-01 -1.66992188e-01
  1.49414062e-01 -1.44531250e-01 -1.22558594e-01  6.39648438e-02
 -2.48046875e-01 -3.30078125e-01  3.93066406e-02 -1.69921875e-01
  4.80957031e-02 -2.01171875e-01 -4.10156250e-01  1.65039062e-01
  2.29492188e-01 -1.45507812e-01 -2.53906250e-01 -2.27539062e-01
  1.33789062e-01  6.83593750e-02 -8.69140625e-02  4.15039062e-02
 -1.96289062e-01  1.69921875e-01  6.54296875e-02  6.34765625e-02
  1.22070312e-01  1.28906250e-01 -4.29687500e-02 -1.12792969e-01
  1.22070312e-01 -1.85546875e-01 -2.89062500e-01 -2.91015625e-01
 -1.98242188e-01  2.50000000e-01  2.46093750e-01  2.14843750e-01
 -1.81640625e-01  6.98852539e-03  3.35937500e-01 -1.90429688e-01
 -1.95312500e-02  4.23828125e-01 -1.04980469e-01 -7.81250000e-02
 -1.31835938e-01 -1.21582031e-01 -1.50756836e-02  1.92382812e-01
  9.03320312e-03  1.70898438e-01  2.83203125e-01 -1.08398438e-01
 -5.07812500e-02 -4.58984375e-02 -1.44531250e-01 -1.38671875e-01
 -3.55468750e-01 -6.44531250e-02 -1.21582031e-01  2.12402344e-02
 -4.68750000e-01  2.34375000e-02 -1.48437500e-01 -1.45507812e-01
  6.98242188e-02 -4.23828125e-01 -3.73535156e-02  1.45507812e-01
 -3.10546875e-01  1.82617188e-01  1.31835938e-01  6.49414062e-02
  3.04687500e-01  2.11914062e-01 -1.84570312e-01 -7.22656250e-02
  1.39648438e-01  5.22460938e-02 -1.01562500e-01 -2.07031250e-01
 -3.98437500e-01 -2.91015625e-01 -1.37695312e-01  3.76953125e-01
 -1.37695312e-01 -1.91406250e-01 -4.05273438e-02 -5.61523438e-02
  2.20947266e-02  3.93066406e-02 -3.39843750e-01  9.32617188e-02
  3.75000000e-01  3.66210938e-02 -2.14843750e-02 -1.67968750e-01
 -3.12500000e-01  1.81884766e-02  1.75781250e-01 -2.79541016e-02
 -4.02343750e-01 -5.20019531e-02  8.88671875e-02 -5.00000000e-01
 -1.25976562e-01 -9.37500000e-02 -2.85156250e-01 -1.66015625e-01
 -1.92382812e-01  2.38281250e-01 -7.78198242e-03  2.00195312e-01
 -1.07421875e-01  2.71484375e-01 -1.25000000e-01 -1.30462646e-03
 -3.88183594e-02 -2.34375000e-01 -1.07910156e-01  4.68750000e-02
  8.78906250e-03 -2.53906250e-01  6.78710938e-02 -6.15234375e-02
 -5.20019531e-02 -9.96093750e-02  2.59765625e-01 -4.07714844e-02
  1.03515625e-01  1.22680664e-02 -1.94335938e-01 -3.65234375e-01
  2.57812500e-01 -4.19921875e-02  6.73828125e-02  1.73828125e-01
  3.29589844e-02 -2.13867188e-01  4.83989716e-05  7.86132812e-02
  7.86132812e-02  1.38671875e-01  1.07910156e-01 -4.10156250e-01
  1.72851562e-01 -1.78710938e-01  6.56127930e-03  1.19628906e-01
  2.55859375e-01 -4.76074219e-02  5.32226562e-02 -3.20312500e-01
 -2.57812500e-01  1.11816406e-01 -1.67968750e-01 -2.73437500e-01
 -4.19921875e-01  2.07031250e-01  8.10546875e-02 -1.47460938e-01
  6.28662109e-03 -5.61523438e-02 -6.25610352e-03  1.25000000e-01
  3.10058594e-02  2.83203125e-02 -3.90625000e-01 -1.04003906e-01
  1.82617188e-01  4.61425781e-02 -1.11389160e-03  2.50000000e-01
  1.77734375e-01 -1.07910156e-01 -3.97949219e-02 -1.62109375e-01
  1.44653320e-02  4.49218750e-01 -1.12792969e-01  1.76757812e-01
 -1.74804688e-01 -3.04687500e-01  3.94531250e-01 -5.93261719e-02
  1.15234375e-01  4.05883789e-03 -2.12890625e-01  2.98828125e-01]
```

Need to do this in loop which is

`

```
def preprocess_and_vectorize(text):
    # remove stop words and lemmatize the text
    doc = nlp(text)
    filtered_tokens = []
    for token in doc:
        if token.is_stop or token.is_punct:
            continue
        filtered_tokens.append(token.lemma_)
        
    return wv[filtered_tokens]
```

This is suppose to be easy while using gensim attribute after return.

```
return wv.get_mean_vector(filtered_tokens)
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.mean`?

Comment: I did actually but, np.mean getting avarage of all 300 elements and giving avarage number of it. My aproach is probably wrong but i couldnt find solution and very sleepy right now ..Thanks for your attempt to help :).

Comment: Read the docs!  It takes an axis parameter

Comment: Look into `.reshape()`, also. But I don't thiink you've yet specified desired result in enough detail. As 2300 is not divisible by 300, it's unclear how many of each pre-operation elements will become one element of the new array, nor how. (Your comment about pairing elements off doesn't help either: replacing each pair of values with 1 mean value would yeild a 1150-element array, still with no clear relation to an eventual 300-element output.) So to get more hints from others, you'll have to be more specific. What's the real source of the original array, & intended use of desired output?